# Groups and Binary Operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Decide which of the following pairs $(G,*)$ are groups; for those which are,
say what the identity and inverses are, and for the ones which aren't, say
which axiom fails.

d. $G=(0,\infty)$ with $*$ given by $g*h :=\sqrt{gh}$

What does this $:=$ mean?

If it means what I think it means, which is that  the binary operation is defined by $\sqrt{gh}$, then would the identity and inverse for $a\in G $ be $a$.

Also, how would I prove associativity i.e. $(g*h)*z=g*(h*z)$

Comment: Your interpretation is correct, but the Identity element must be _the_ identity, independent of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $:=$ means "is defined to be". The set you give is not a group under that operation as there is no unique identity element.